# Neo4J RelationShip Update (MATCH SET) slow

Tags: performance, neo4j, set, match

I have a query:

```
PROFILE MATCH ()-[r]-() WHERE ID(r) = 35467410 SET r.canRead = True, r.canWrite = False
```

[image]

That takes 16 seconds ... and 38,358,201 db hits. I don't understand why.

But when I remove SET:

```
PROFILE MATCH ()-[r]-() WHERE ID(r) = 35467410 RETURN *
```

[image]

It's instantaneous.

Comment: Lookups by id are a seek operation and should only incur 1 db hit (as your second query plan shows). What version of Neo4j are you using? I'm unable to reproduce this on Neo4j 3.0.3.

Comment: hi i work with 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been logged in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/3064

As @cleishm suggested, you can workaround it with `START r=rel(35467410) SET r.canRead = True, r.canWrite = False`

Comment: Thanks ;) your are my hero ;)